# Datasource not able to initialize via Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am creating a Spring boot application where I am initializing datasource in spring file. But getting below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.JdbcCustomerDAO.insert(JdbcCustomerDAO.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.EmployeeController.getCustomer(EmployeeController.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org
```

Getting NullPointerException on below line:

```
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

My source code is there on github 
https://github.com/thesnehajain/spring_boot/tree/master/springbootdemo

Comment: That's because `dataSource` is not getting injected; try constructor injection by using the `@Autowired` annotation and later on tweak it to use setter injection

Comment: Stil giving same error after putting annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your XML files (all of them!).

Make a new file `application.properties` inside `src/main/resources` and put this inside it:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://rdssample.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/customer
spring.datasource.username = rdssample
spring.datasource.password = rdssample
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

...that should make the trick!

Spring Boot is all about conventions and discovery so you don't have to define, declare (keep on) all your beans and dependencies. You can acquire a lot of them just be declaring a few "properties".

**UPDATE**

Spring config, in both "flavors" (XML and Java classes), is allowed under Spring Boot, but again, Spring Boot applications need very little to no configuration, with absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration. It may look like a traditional Spring MVC application, but it's actually very different. Have a look at the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/), you will find a lot of useful tips and examples.

Moreover, in your case, if you want to configure your data source via Java config, you can do something similar to this:

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        .username("rdssample")
        .password("rdssample")
        .url("jdbc:mysql://rdssample.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/customer")
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is spring config not allowed in springboot applications? Meanwhile I am trying your solution.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution has worked. But could you answer my above question?

Comment: I put and "update" clause in the answer itself for future references in case someone has to do the same change(s)

Comment: So when someone who see's a correct answer and wants to make sure the extra properties get added gets voted down? So for the Spring Boot people here are the properties that will come in handy 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Have a  nice day!